# My python interpreter runs in interactive mode on its own

Tags: python, shell, pycharm, interpreter, interactive

Python version : 3.6.1

Pycharm version : 2018.1 EAP (Professional Edition)

My python interpreter runs in interactive mode ***ON ITS OWN!!***

[I just ran the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihpAK.png)

I ran the python script in PyCharm in the way that I usually did.

The interpreter had worked very well until the last night(2018/01/31) but...

[But the interpreter has been changed like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWqGA.png)

it has been changed in interactive mode ***AUTOMATICALLY***.

I did just sleep, wake up and run it.

[This is what actually I had seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOpbE.png)

ran like this until the last night.
(I brought it from Google because I don't have a capture.)

[PyCharm Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFvex.png)

But that doesn't mean that `-i` is in the interpreter option.

I got some solution that unchecking 
**"Show command line afterwards"** box works, but I cannot find it.

```
import sys
print(sys.flags.interactive) # 0
```

Checked interactive flag is `False`.

It is kinda useful using interactive interpreter but I am now just uncomfortable for it.

**How do I change it to uninteractive???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Run > Edit configurations...* menu. Select *Python > your-script-name* on the left and un-check the option *Show command line afterwards* on the right:

[image: option shown]

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the option in Run > Edit Configurations